# What is the differential of a function?

Tags: differential-forms

I'm reading Do Carmo's Differential Forms and Applications (1st ed) and on page 6 he takes a differentiable map $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$, a point $p \in  \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}_{p}^{n}$ (where $\mathbb{R}_{p}^{n} = \{ q-p: q\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \}$ is the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in $p$), and then defines something in terms of $df_{p}(v)$, where $df_{p}: \mathbb{R}_{p}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{f(p)}^{m}$ is "the differential of the map $f$ at $p$".

My questions are:

(i) What is the differential of the map $f$ at $p$?

(ii) How can I calculate it in some specific vector like $v$?

Comment: At this level of abstraction, the differential operator is the Jacobian.  You will get into more abstract (algebraic) definitions later, I presume.

Comment: The problem is that he does not define it anywhere on this chapter.

Comment: Have you taken a course on multivariable derivatives yet?

Answer (score 1):

This post seems old but it might help to answer it for people who stumble across.

Let me first describe the setting. Let $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set $p\in U$ and $f:U\to \mathbb R^m$ be a $C^1$ function. Furthermore let us identify $(\mathbb R^n)_p$ with $\mathbb R^n$ itself by the obvious isomorphism.

The total derivative of the function $f$ at the point $p$ is the best linear approximation of $f$ at that point. If $f$ is differentiable (in our case it is since $f$ is $C^1$) there exists a linear map $df_p:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ such that the following holds:
$$\frac{\|f(p+h)-f(p) - df_p(h)\|}{\|h\|}\to 0\text{, } \text{as }h\to 0.$$
The linear map $df_p$ is called the total derivative of $f$ at the point $p$.
We can also formalise it in a different way. The differential of $f$ at the point $p$ is the linear map $df_p$ so that

$$f(p+h)-f(p) = df_p(h) +R(h),$$
where $R(h)$ satisfies $$\frac{\|R(h)\|}{\|h\|}\to 0 \text{, as }h\to 0.$$

This might be a bit abstract and formal, so let us work with some examples.

Consider the map $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = \langle x,a\rangle$ for a fixed $a\in \mathbb R^n$. We can compute the differential of $f$ at a point $p$ in the following way: First consider the difference $f(p+h) - f(p)$, we see that
$$f(p+h)-f(p) = \langle p+h,a\rangle -\langle p,a\rangle = \langle h,a\rangle.$$
If we analyse this and take all the linear parts (in this case everything), then we can. conclude that the differential of $f$ at $p$ is given by $f$ itself, meaning $df_p(h)=f(h)$ for all $h\in \mathbb R^n$.
Intuitively this makes a lot of sense, because the differential is the best linear approximation at a certain point. Well our map is linear to begin with, so the best linear approximation should be given by the map itself!

Now a more difficult example. Consider the map $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ given by $x\mapsto \langle x ,x \rangle$ and consider the difference
$$f(p+h)-f(p) = \langle p+h,p+h\rangle - \langle p,p\rangle = 2\langle p,h\rangle + \langle h,h\rangle.$$
Note that the map $h\mapsto 2\langle p,h\rangle$ is linear and the map $h\mapsto \langle h,h \rangle $ is not linear. So let us check whether $R(h) = \langle h,h \rangle $ goes to $0$ "fast enough".
$$\frac{|R(h)|}{\|h\|} = \frac{|\langle h,h \rangle |}{\|h\|} \leq \frac{\|h\|^2}{\|h\|}\to 0\text{, as }h\to 0.$$
Using the squeezing theorem we obtain that
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|R(h)|}{\|h\|} = 0.$$
The differential of $f$ at $p$ is thus given by $$df_p(h) = 2\langle p,h\rangle .$$

Might worth the notice that your second question can be answered in different ways.

1. You can calculate $df_p(v)$ for a vector $v$ by first computing $df_p$ and then letting it work on a vector $v$.
2. You can use the following formula $$df_p(v) = \frac{d}{dt} f(p+tv)\vert_{t=0}.$$

And one last thing worth the notice as well is the fact that the differential of a function at a point $p$ is unique and it coincides with the Jacobi matrix evaluated at the point $p$.